# Ignore c# fields dynamically from Json Serialize

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

For API purposes I need to ignore some fields based on criteria I receive. Usually I could use `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute to do this.

**But how I can ignore fields dynamically (based on some conditionals)?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [JsonIgnore](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonignoreattribute.htm) attribute available in Newtonsoft.Json package.

then, if you want it to be dynamically conditional, see [ShouldSerialize](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/04/15/conditionally-serializing-fields-and-properties-with-jsonnet#conditionally-serializing-object-members)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you use `Json.Net`, you can create your own converter for a specific type by creating a class that inherits from `JsonConverter`.

```
public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var objectToSerialize = new {}; //create the object you want to serialize here, based on your dynamic conditions
        new JsonSerializer().Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize); //serialize the object to the current writer
    }
}
```

Then you call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and pass it your custom converter:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(jsonString, new MyJsonConverter());
```